# How to retrieve all data of the current User in controller?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I need take all data of the current user which is logged in and send it in JSON format into the route "/home". I was searching how to do it, but nothing.. I found that i can take only username and authorities [there](https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security). Can someone help me to handle it? Thanks all.

There is my **AuthController.java**

```
    // Getting all user data
    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUsersDataById(Principal principal) {
        return principal.getName();
    }
```

There is my **UserRepository**

```
import com.example.demo.Models.Users;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer> {
    Optional<Users> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

There are my services:
**MyUserDetails.java**

```
public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String last_login_date;
    private String registration_date;
    private String last_login_ip;
    private Integer balance;
    private Integer status;
    private String brith_date;
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    private boolean active;

    public MyUserDetails(Users user) {
        this.username = user.getUsername();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.authorities = Arrays.stream(user.getRoles().split(","))
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        this.active = user.isActive();
    }

    public MyUserDetails(String username, String firstname, String lastname, String email, String last_login_date, String registration_date, String last_login_ip, Integer balance, Integer status, String brith_date) {
        this.username = username;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
        this.last_login_date = last_login_date;
        this.registration_date = registration_date;
        this.last_login_ip = last_login_ip;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.status = status;
        this.brith_date = brith_date;
    }

    public MyUserDetails() {
    }
//  and Override methods by default..
```

**MyUserDetailsService**

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<Users> user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        user.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Not found: " + username));

        return user.map(MyUserDetails::new).get();
    }
}
```

There is **Users.java** with columns from table and geters and setters without constructor

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String username;
    ...
    /// etc..

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    ...
    // etc..
```

Comment: See answer below. I hope it solved the issue. If it did. Accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotate your method with @AuthenticationPrincipal and use UserDetails.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Userdetails getUsersDataById(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails) {


        return userDetails;
    }
```

Comment: Yes that's true.

Comment: He wants all information, so just return the `UserDetails`, if it was the name the `Principal` approach would be enough.

Comment: Finally, I found what I wanted! Thanks!